# TeeChart Pro DragMarks tool How to move Custom Mark position relative to their points when dragging

Tags: delphi, teechart

In Teechart pro Delphi VCL, the custom Marks have **absolute** position.
When the user is dragging (PAN, right-mouse), the Marks stay at their position and not moved together with the points and keep a relative position.
Is there a property to define the custom position to be **relative**?
If not, how to do it in code?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8441&p=34033#p34033). If you still find problems with it, please edit your question adding a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yerey, I read the post and still have a problem how to do it. Any hint will be great. The user is moveing the Marks, it is not a known place by code. Is tSeriesMarkPosition store the offset? probably not. I need a way to catch all old absolute Marks location before any movement, Zoom/UnZoom/Pan - how?, then after the movement was completed to recalulate absolute Marks location, maybe with ChartAfter Draw event. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: The `Positions` array stores the absolute positions of the marks. You can maintain another array with positions relative to the points. You should update this array at the `TDragMarksTool` events. You should update the `Positions` array at OnZoom/OnUndoZoom/OnScroll events. You can use the series `CalcXPos(ValueIndex)` and `CalcYPos(ValueIndex)` to transform your relative positions to absolute positions (and viceversa)